Layer Feature Id Number
I have a short Python action that creates a new shape file for any feature that you click on in the layer.  That part all works fine.  When you zoom out it will select multiple feature and give you a choice of which (or all) feature to select, that is fine too.  Problem is the attribute that it displays is not an attribute that is particularly helpful as to what the feature is.

I am guessing this is based on the fact that QGIS creates an Id field and simply picks what ever field is at Id = 0 to use in the selection window.  Is there any way to change this, such as in my case, it would be much better to use the field value at Id = 3?

Mycode:
from qgis.utils import iface

CableGroup = '[%CABLEGROUP%]'
feature_id = [%$id%]
layer_id = '[%@layer_id%]'

layer = QgsProject.instance().mapLayer(layer_id)

new_layer = layer.materialize(
    QgsFeatureRequest().setFilterFids([feature_id]))
    
new_layer.setName(CableGroup)
QgsProject.instance().addMapLayer(new_layer)
iface.setActiveLayer(layer)


The attribute shown in the list of clicked features in a layer Action comes from the layer's Display property. To change this setting, open the Layer Properties Dialog and go to the Display tab. There you can change the field used for Display Name. In your case change it to the "CABLEGROUP" field.

You can also click the ε expression button to enter an expression for the display property e.g. concatenating two fields etc.
